# Python 3 module importing issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module

I'm new to Python and still trying to figure out its module importing.

Here is what I have in each module:

utils.py

```
def find_max(numbers):
    maximum = numbers[0]
    for number in numbers:
        if maximum < number:
            maximum = number
    return maximum
```

utils_2.py

```
def find_min(numbers):
    minimum = numbers[0]
    for number in numbers:
        if minimum > number:
            minimum = number
    return minimum
```

app.py

```
import utils
print(utils.find_max([3, 6, 2]))

from utils_2 import find_min
print(find_min([3, 6, 1]))
```

The first way (import the entire module) to import utils by "import utils" works fine, since the terminal did print out 6.

However, the second way (import just single function within a module) to import utils_2 by "from utils_2 import find_min" did not work, and was hoping it would print out 1.

Am I misunderstanding anything in importing modules in Python different ways? Thanks for the explanation!

[EDIT: Added a screenshot below for more information about my file structures/directories. Hope this can help identifying the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1MrF.png)

Comment: And what do you mean by "did not work" exactly? You're not printing the second result.

Comment: @DallogFheir edited. thanks for pointing that out. i tried to print it before, but the terminal said "ImportError: cannot import name 'find_min' from 'utils_2' "

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me, make sure that both the files are in the same directory as app.py file

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the recommendation. But they are in the same directories with app.py. Added a screenshot too, hoping that could help identifying the problems here.

Answer (score 0):

**I thought so, following the below instructions:**
Your understanding of importing modules in Python is generally correct. However, the issue you're encountering might be due to the way you're organizing your files or how you're running your code.

Based on the code you provided, your module organization seems fine. Here's what might be happening:

**Module Locations and Execution:**
First, make sure that all three of your Python files (utils.py, utils_2.py, and app.py) are in the same directory. This is important because Python will look for modules in the current directory by default.

**Running app.py:**
When you run app.py, ensure that you are executing it from the same directory where the utils.py and utils_2.py files are located.

**Check for Typos:**
Double-check that there are no typos in the filenames or function names.

**Avoid Circular Imports:**
Circular imports occur when two or more modules depend on each other. Make sure that you're not creating a circular dependency between your modules.

If you're still facing issues, try the following steps:

Restart your Python interpreter or the terminal where you're running the code. Sometimes, changes to files might not be immediately recognized.
Ensure you're using a Python version that supports the module import syntax you're using (Python 3 is recommended).
Explicitly set the PYTHONPATH environment variable to the directory containing your Python files to ensure that Python can find them.
If you continue to encounter problems, providing more information about your file structure and how you're executing the code would help in diagnosing the issue further.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for all the recommendations. I tried checking them all and they all looked good to me, unless I'm understanding something wrong here. Added a screenshot for more info on my file directories!